# how to sort values from a column and assign ranks to them

Tags: php

I'm creating a web application for a school, m stuck at a point. i have a column that contains the averages for each student, i want to rank the values from the average column and then sort them and them for the highest i assign a value for their position(the highest should be assigned 1st position and the second highest value should be assigned 2nd and so on.
this is what i have done so far. like i said m stuck. need help

```
<?php 
$results = mysql_query("SELECT average FROM ss3goldresult ORDER by average DESC");
average = array();                      
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$average[] =$row['average'];  
$avg = $average;                 
}print_r ($avg); ?>
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated! Please prefer PDO or mysqli functions.

Comment: done so, using the mysqli functions now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now what is your need?I can help you more. As question is not clear, I just give you dummy code,
first you need student name also for ranking, so select student also.

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT student, average FROM ss3goldresult ORDER by average DESC");
$html ="";
$i=1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $html .= "<p>".$row['student']." got $i rank</p>";
   $i++;
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: thanks sir, ur reply worked, it gave me a big idea on what to do from now on.
PS: i edited this tho while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
foreach($average as $a){
  print_r($i.'. '.$a);
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: No problem! :) if you find someone's answer useful - please add positive vote for it using "up" arrow placed left to the answer. If answer also solves your problem don't forget to check the "V" like check also placed left to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: i did press the "up" error but was denied, bcos of my reputaion.